# Command not found running in shell script

Tags: bash, windows

I'm running git-bash on windows.  I feel the issue I'm facing is more of a NIX geared question than windows.  I have a shell script:

#### build.sh

```
myProject="../myProject/"
build="gulp build"

cd "${myProject}"
pwd
"${build}"
```

When I run this script I get error

> gulp build: command not found

When I run "gulp build" directly in the shell, running these same commands by hand then everything works.  I tried executing the script via:

`. build.sh` and just `build.sh`

Same error either way.  How can I run a script that can access gulp/npm?  Why does this fail even when I am sourcing the script?

Comment: try just ${build}?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting `"${build}"` prevents word splitting, so it has the same effect here as writing `"gulp build"` (with quotes), which would search for an executable called `gulp build` with a space inside the name; and not as writing `gulp build`, which executes `gulp` with a `build` argument.

Concluding, the last line of your script should be:

```
${build}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do not quote `"${build}"`. As it expects in such a case `gulp build` command (with a space inside) and reports rightfully such command does not exist.

Execute simply by `${build}`. Then shell will treat it as a command and arguments.

```
myProject="../myProject/"
build="gulp build"

cd "${myProject}"
pwd
${build}
```

Comment: That solved it.  Can you link me/provide more detail on when to use quotes?  I'm finding it to be a difficult decision.

Comment: I just added more info in the answer, but the general rule is it will treat the quoted string as one piece. If an argument requires a space inside, then you should quote.